# Looking for a good way to parse command-line arguments in C# for an app that is similar to tf.exe (VS2010) in cli language complexity

Tags: c#, parsing, .net-4.0, command-line-arguments, hierarchy

The [tf.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0.aspx) is the CLI interface to the Team Foundation Server.

In my case the complexity and structure of the permutations of the command-line switches is similar. There are about two dozen of different report types in a GUI app that I am trying to drive from command line (I can do those things through an add-in), and there will be about half-dozen different commands. I will start by implementing the simplest functionality, but then will add complexity as I have more time. This means that this will keep on evolving, and I will never know the exhaustive list of all possible permutations.

In general, the cli syntax will be:

```
Manipulate.exe <Command> <ReportType> <Followed by options that depend on the first two switches>
```

For example:

```
Manipulate.exe Open ABCReport /option1:"1 2 3" [/option2:2 [/option3:"3 3"]] | /option4:4 | /option5
Manipulate.exe Open XYZReport /option1:"1 2 3" /option2:2 [/option3]
...
Manipulate.exe Close ABCReport (/reportid:987 | /reportmnemonic:"ABC12 Report")
Manipulate.exe Close XYZReport (/reportid:876 | /reportmnemonic:"ZYZ98 Report")
...
Manipulate.exe Refresh ABCReport (/reportid:987 | /reportmnemonic:"ABC12 Report")
Manipulate.exe Refresh XYZReport (/reportid:876 | /reportmnemonic:"ZYZ98 Report")
...
Manipulate.exe SelectRows ABCReport (/reportid:987 | /reportmnemonic:"ABC12 Report") <followed by select criteria flags>
Manipulate.exe SelectRows XYZReport (/reportid:876 | /reportmnemonic:"ZYZ98 Report") <followed by select criteria flags>
....
```

Due to complexity of this I am thinking of rolling my own parsing logic at least partially, e.g. there would be an `abstract` `ReportOpener`, `ReportCloser`, `ReportRefresher`, `ReportRowsSelector`, etc. class (all children of abstract `ReportManipulator`), and then more concrete classes such as `ABCReportOpener`, `ABCReportRowSelector`, etc. which will have to implement `PrintUsage`, `ParseArguments`, `PerformAction`. There can be a simple dispatcher which looks at the first two arguments, makes sure that command and report type are valid, and then tries to dispatch on this combination (if it is implemented / can be found) by creating the right subclass.

I think I would need abstract classes - that way the parent class can implement some of the common work. However, the dispatching in my case is not arbitrary as in a multi-method dispatch, but hierarchical, so I would like to leverage the power of OO somehow. If only `ReportOpener`, `ReportCloser`, `ReportRefresher`, `ReportManipulator` could be instantiated and had the knowledge of all its children as well as the ability to fetch the right child based on the value of just ONE command-line switch ... but then they cannot be `abstract`.

Is this a reasonable approach for this task or can you suggest something better?
What is the best library to parse the remaining (third through last) arguments, given the sample syntax above?